# The interface XXXXX cannot be implemented more than once with different arguments

Tags: java, swing

i'm currently working on salomé tmf project so i downloaded the code after compiling it 
i'm getting this error :

```
 The interface ListCellRenderer cannot be implemented more than once with different   
 arguments: ListCellRenderer<Object> and ListCellRenderer   UserListRenderer.java
```

but i can not find where is  the problem exactly .
**Here's the code of  class UserListRenderer :**

```
package org.objectweb.salome_tmf.ihm.admin.models;

import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.ListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

import org.objectweb.salome_tmf.api.ApiConstants;
import org.objectweb.salome_tmf.api.Util;
import org.objectweb.salome_tmf.data.AdminProjectData;
import org.objectweb.salome_tmf.data.User;
import org.objectweb.salome_tmf.ihm.IHMConstants;
import org.objectweb.salome_tmf.ihm.tools.Tools;


 public class UserListRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer implements    
 ListCellRenderer, ApiConstants , IHMConstants{

/**
 * Le s?parateur de fichier
 */
/**
 * M?thode qui red?finit le renderer des ?l?ments de la liste
 * @param list la liste concern?e
 * @param value l'objet dans la liste
 * @param index indice dans la liste
 * @param isSelected si l'objet est s?lectionn?
 * @param cellHasFocus si le focus est sur la cellule
 */
public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index,
boolean isSelected,
boolean cellHasFocus) {
    if (isSelected) {
        setBackground(list.getSelectionBackground());
        setForeground(list.getSelectionForeground());
    }
    else {
        setBackground(list.getBackground());
        setForeground(list.getForeground());
    }
    Icon icon;
    if (value instanceof User) {
        icon = Tools.createAppletImageIcon(PATH_TO_ADMIN_ICON,"");
        setIcon(icon);
        setText(((User)value).getLoginFromModel() + " / " + 
       ((User)value).getLastNameFromModel() + " " + 
       ((User)value).getFirstNameFromModel());
    } else if (value instanceof Icon) {
        setIcon((Icon)value);
        setText("");
    } else {
        setIcon(null);
        setText((value == null) ? "" : value.toString());
    }

    setEnabled(list.isEnabled());
    setFont(list.getFont());
    setBorder((cellHasFocus) ? UIManager.getBorder("List.focusCellHighlightBorder") : 
     noFocusBorder);

    return this;

   } // Fin de la m?thode getListCellRendererComponent/5
 }  // Fin de la classe UserListRenderer
```

Any help will be appreciated

Cheers

Comment: It looks to be a problem of conflicting generic arguments. What if you remove ListCellRenderer from your implements list? There's no need for you to declare it in the interface list since the parent class, DefaultListCellRenderer, already implements it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels when i remove it the code is now correct but  will this affect the execution of the application ?

Comment: `"Will this affect the execution...?"`: no. Again the interface is already taken care of by the parent class.

Comment: ok i got it now many thanks to you guys :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using Java 6 or Java 7? In Java 7 the interface seems to have been redesigned to take generic arguments. I suggest you try omitting the `implements ListCellRenderer` first - it is not needed because DefaultListCellRenderer already implements it.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to make `UserListRenderer` implement the generic interface `ListCellRenderer<T>` twice with different `T`s. This isn't allowed.

Comment: From the looks of it you should be able to remove the `ListCellRenderer` from the `implements` list, but it's really not possible to tell for sure without a more thorough look through the code.